# Как получить параметры post запроса в express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Код на сервере:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
 
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query);
    res.send('1')
  })
 
app.listen(3000)
```

из браузера пытаюсь отправить запрос и прочитать в консоль параметры req.query

```js
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    method: 'post',
    data: {text: 'Текст'},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

в итоге получаю пустой объект req.query.
Если отправлять запрос по http://localhost:3000/?id=1, то в req.query придет {id:1} даже при условии, что это post запрос.

Comment: Вы и не отправляете параметров. Вы отправляете тело запроса. Для его прочтения используется `req.body`, однако для начала нужно установить парсер, например, body-parser

Comment: Спасибо всем, благодаря ответам решение было найдено!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пакет [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// ...

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// ...

app.post('/simple', async(req, res)=>{
    console.log('simple', req.body);
});
```

Еще в ajax добавь: `dataType: 'json'`